# How can you tell if a scheduled (rake) task is currently running on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Heroku scheudler tells you when a scheduled rake task was last *started*, e.g.

[image]

Obviously many things can go wrong during a long task (bad code, server issues, the list goes on).

Is there any way to tell if a particular scheduled task *is currently running*? i.e. not just that it started, but that it's in progress? Is there some way to tell?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scheduler spins up a one-off dyno when it runs, which will show up under the app's process list with `heroku ps` and related commands: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#stopping-one-off-dynos - The process will have a prefix of `scheduler` (ie. `scheduler.1`). `ps` will also return the name of the command being executed, which allows you to differentiate between tasks if required.